# How can I make my Anaconda environment "recognize"/activate an .so file in anaconda/envs/envname/lib?

Tags: python, anaconda

While having Anaconda environment `envname` activated, `conda list` yields installed packages.

However, in the directory `anaconda/envs/envname/lib` there are `.so` files that aren't listed above (e.g., the symbolic link file `libavcodec.so.57`).

Furthermore, when running some Python code that depends on `libavcodec.so.57` (while in the `envname` environment), I get:

```
ImportError: libavcodec.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I make my Anaconda environment "recognize" (i.e., display in "conda list" and use at Python program runtime) `libavcodec.so.57` in `anaconda/envs/envname/lib`?

Comment: Thanks! What package installs that `.so` file? That package will be listed in the output of `conda list`, not the `.so` specifically. Also, how was your Python code compiled?

Comment: ffmpeg. The question is resolved: I noticed that the symbolic link libavcodec.so.57 did not point to the correct (previous version) file and corrected it. Other issues arose that are beyond the scope of this question. Thanks for the follow up in any case.